# I can not use aries jpa/v2.0.0 and transactions/v2.0.0

Tags: java, xml, jpa, osgi

I tried enable  and  int blueprint.xml but I have error. It is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:jpa="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v2.0.0"
           xmlns:tx="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v2.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
           http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v2.0.0
           http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v2.0.0 ">
    <jpa:enable/>
    <tx:enable-annotations/>
    <service ref="userService" interface="domain.access.UserService"/>
    <bean id="userService" class="domain.access.impl.UserServiceImpl" scope="singleton">
    </bean>
</blueprint>
```

It is my dependencies in pom.xml I include all libs  mabe I forgot somthing

```
<dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>sqljdbc41</groupId>
               <artifactId>sqljdbc41</artifactId>
               <version>4.1</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
               <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-dbcp</artifactId>
               <version>1.4_3</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
               <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
               <version>1.1</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
               <artifactId>geronimo-validation_1.0_spec</artifactId>
               <version>1.1</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
               <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
               <version>1.1.1</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
               <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
               <version>2.4.1</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>kg.nurtelecom</groupId>
               <artifactId>access-module-api</artifactId>
               <version>1.0.0</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>domain</groupId>
               <artifactId>platform-common</artifactId>
               <version>1.0.0</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
               <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
               <version>1.2</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
```

and when I start bundle I have grace period and in log

```
2016-03-05 12:34:37,732 | INFO  | l for user karaf | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 15 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.4.4 | Bundle kg.nurtelecom.access.module.impl/1.0.0 is waiting for name
space handlers [http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v2.0.0, http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v2.0.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the transaction 2.0.0 namespace the xml element is named `<tx:enable/>` not `<tx:enable-annotations/>`. This is not related to the error you described though.

The error says that you do not have the correct Aries JPA bundle installed. Be sure you install all necessary features like in [this example](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/blob/master/tasklist-blueprint-cdi/features/src/main/resources/features.xml).

The dependencies in the pom cover only the build time. At runtime you have to provide the dependencies as karaf features or individual bundles.

Also make sure you use the newest Apache Karaf. Older versions did not include the aries transaction 2.0.0 bundle.

Comment: I have 3.0.6 karaf. Is it include the aries transaction 2.0.0 bundle? I change  <tx:enable-annotations/> to <tx:enable/>, but <jpa:enable/> whatever highlighted in IDE

Comment: You will need karaf 4.

Comment: I can not use this functional in karaf 3.0.6? And I not found where I need change Aries JPA bundle, Can you write the rows I need to change? I have a few places where the registered features.  now I change this: <!--<feature>jpa/2.0.0</feature>-->
                        <feature version="[2.2, 3)">jpa</feature>